# Changing previous input - Python

Tags: python

So, lets say I had code like this:

```
a = []
x = input('>>> ')
a.append(x)
n = input('>>> ')
a.append(n)
```

using cursor navigation would it be possible to (while you are still inputting n) to change the value of b? Anyway thanks!

Comment: Where is b? I don’t understand what you mean by cursor navigation. Would you mind expanding your question?

Comment: b? and also cursor navigation means via going up a line in the console and changing input

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Once you press enter and sumbit the input x you can not change it.

Comment: Oh, okay that is a bummer.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What would the code do?

Comment: Perhaps you can refine the algorithm in such a way that it handles command like `-e` (edit) `-c` (commit) etc? Whatever is on the output screen will stay there  however. If that's what the question is about: you cannot change what is written on the output screen, but you can change (with an algorithm) what's stored in a variable.